# Did I override the Win10 Bootloader with Ubuntu

Tags: 16.04, bootloader, windows-10

I just installed Ubuntu witch is working fine. But If I try to start WIN10 within the boot-loader the boot-loader restarts itself.

I have chosen the partition for the Ubuntu Boot-loader, where the WIN10 boot-loader was before. So have i overridden the Windows boot-loader?

[BootInfo PasteBin Link](http://paste2.org/CCIJB1kg)

```
sudo fdisk -l
Disk /dev/sda: 465,8 GiB, 500107862016 bytes, 976773168 sectors
Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 4096 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 4096 bytes / 4096 bytes
Disklabel type: gpt
Disk identifier: 98397ECD-029E-11E6-9C2F-28D244306994

Device         Start       End   Sectors   Size Type
/dev/sda1         34    262177    262144   128M Microsoft reserved
/dev/sda2     264192 532744191 532480000 253,9G Microsoft basic data
/dev/sda3  532744192 976773119 444028928 211,7G Microsoft basic data

Partition 1 does not start on physical sector boundary.


Disk /dev/sdb: 238,5 GiB, 256060514304 bytes, 500118192 sectors
Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
Disklabel type: dos
Disk identifier: 0x7720062f

Device     Boot     Start       End   Sectors  Size Id Type
/dev/sdb1  *         2048   1026047   1024000  500M  7 HPFS/NTFS/exFAT
/dev/sdb2         1026048 307202047 306176000  146G  7 HPFS/NTFS/exFAT
/dev/sdb3       307204094 500117503 192913410   92G  5 Extended
/dev/sdb5       307204096 483981311 176777216 84,3G 83 Linux
/dev/sdb6       483983360 500117503  16134144  7,7G 82 Linux swap / Solaris


sudo blkid
/dev/sda1: PARTLABEL="Microsoft reserved partition" PARTUUID="98397ece-029e-11e6-9c2f-28d244306994"
/dev/sda2: UUID="174014076A235FDC" TYPE="ntfs" PARTLABEL="Backup" PARTUUID="c48f685e-bb1b-43bf-abc9-0ce1896f1811"
/dev/sda3: UUID="18B3C7915C4A1962" TYPE="ntfs" PARTLABEL="Daten" PARTUUID="1939b804-4840-4ada-b864-eb87d4164a0c"
/dev/sdb1: LABEL="System-reserviert" UUID="DA6E17C76E179B79" TYPE="ntfs" PARTUUID="7720062f-01"
/dev/sdb2: UUID="942630B126309668" TYPE="ntfs" PARTUUID="7720062f-02"
/dev/sdb5: UUID="7202b878-632a-488e-ace7-0c731ea761ed" TYPE="ext4" PARTUUID="7720062f-05"
/dev/sdb6: UUID="7b96106a-5bfe-485f-b4bd-85bc5dd91ef7" TYPE="swap" PARTUUID="7720062f-06"
```

Comment: Could you please run [Boot-Info](//help.ubuntu.com/community/Boot-Info) and [edit] your question to include a link to its resulting info log? Thanks.

Comment: Please [edit] the question to replace `witch` with `which` so that English translating software can parse the question accurately.

Answer (score 0):

Probably yes...

If the first bootmenu you see is GRUB now....yes.

I have same situation.
Used to have a Windows7 besides a Kubuntu.
After I Added new HDD to my PC and installed a new Kubuntu from USB on that drive.

During install I choose bootloader location /dev/sda 
(this is default I believe)

So now it boots into GRUB and I see my Windows7 in the GRUB menu, where I used to have a windows bootloader there.

If it is a problem for you you could try "EasyBCD" for windows.See what that tells you.

For Ubuntu you can have a look at "Grub Customizer"

Comment: What happens if you select Win7 within Grub? You also end within a restarted Grub?

Comment: it works.... boots normally

Comment: At least it shows me the Windows bootloader and I need to choose again... Funny thing is in the Windows  bootloader there is a Kubuntu entry which I can hit and I am back to GRUB loader

Answer (score 0):

The thing is that in the install progress when you define the partition under the partitions there is a part where asks *"Device for boot loader install"*

If you choose default(**sda**) then it will install **grub over windows bootloader** and delete windows boot manager.

However if you choose the partition that you install ubuntu on it(**f.e. sda4**) then it **will not** override windows boot manager and you still able to use it. Last time i used Windows with Ubuntu i realized that and configured so my main bootloader was windows bootloader but i still could choose ubuntu partition as an option.

And for the solution try to use "sudo update-grub". Did the machine sees your windows partition? After that restart the computer and try to reach windows partition.

Comment: Sudo update-grub finds the Win10 Loader on /dev/sdb1 but i am still not reaching windows within grub, there ist the Option fpr Win10 Loader but i still restarts the grub loader itself

Comment: @Raros oh no... it looks like you broke something on Windows bootloader. Best to take a repair disk/usb and try to repair windows partition manager.